# Java Spring Webflux - usage of Mono.error(new MyCustomException()) in a reactive pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Small question regarding the usage of Mono.error(new MyCustomException()) in a reactive pipeline please

I have a very simple business use case: using Spring Webflux

- Step 1: Make a HTTP call to a third party rest API.
- depending on the response of this first party rest API, use a map function to transform the response to MyPojo if only the first response is eligible. But if it is not eligible, a custom exception should be thrown.

Therefore, I wrote the following:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/question")
    public Mono<MyPojo> question(String key) {
        return WebClient.create("http://first-service.com/get" + key).get().exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)) //Mono<String>
        .map(oneString -> convertOneStringToMyPojoIfStringIsEligible(oneString));
    }

    private MyPojo convertOneStringToMyPojoIfStringIsEligible(String oneString) {
        if (oneString.startsWith("eligible")) {
            return new MyPojo(oneString);
        } else {
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomException("oneString is not eligible.")); //This is not possible
        }
    }
```

What is the correct approach please?

If possible, without throwing a RuntimeException, without using a flatMap + Mono.just(new MyPojo(oneString)) please?

Thank you

Comment: i see no problems at all with this code, what do you want to happen?

Comment: the convertOneStringToMyPojoIfStringIsEligible does not compile, it is supposed to be a straightforward method to do String -> MyPojo, but I need to Mono.error()

Comment: And thanks for taking a look @Toerktumlare

Comment: oh, i see now. You are using `map` which converts something from one type to another. You see `MyPojo` and a `Mono` are different types, so `map` cant return one or the other type. It has to be the same type. In this case i would suggest that you instead use `flatMap` and return a `Mono.just(new MyPojo(oneString)):`

Comment: if you want to get better at these things i suggest you read up on java generics and then maybe find a tutorial or two of how to implement `map` and `flatMap` in java. And get better at Types and the Typesystem in general, its a very good skill as a developer.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my question: "If possible, without throwing a RuntimeException, without using a flatMap + Mono.just(new MyPojo(oneString)) please?", and also reason why I am asking, is because here is also a good way to "get better!"

Comment: Why make it harder then it needs to be with a lot if… without… without… without…. Its like asking how do i build a car without wheels? You dont get better by excluding tools, you get better by using the tools given to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in addition to what @Toerktumlare has suggested in the comments, is to use a `filter` in combination with `switchIfEmpty`

```
WebClient.create("http://first-service.com/get" + key)
                .get()
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .filter(s -> s.startsWith("eligible"))
                .map(s -> new MyPojo(s))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("oneString is not eligible.")));
```

Personally, unless you need access to other parts of the response apart from the body, I would default to using `retrieve` over `exchangeToMono`. Though this is just personal preference

```
WebClient.create("http://first-service.com/get" + key)
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .filter(s -> s.startsWith("eligible"))
                .map(s -> new MyPojo(s))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("oneString is not eligible.")))
```